# Squares vertices in a 22x16 grid in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

This is my code for creating a 22x16 grid in pygame:

```
import pygame  
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((440, 320))

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, [self.x * WIDTH, self.y * HEIGHT, WIDTH, HEIGHT], 1)
        pygame.display.update()


cols = 22
rows = 16
WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 20
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREY = (127,127,127)
grid = [0 for i in range(cols)]

for node in range(cols):
    grid[node] = [0 for node in range(rows)]

for x in range(cols):
    for y in range(rows):
        grid[x][y] = Grid(x, y)

for x in range(cols):
    for y in range(rows):
        grid[x][y].draw()

while True: 
    event = pygame.event.get()
    if event == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
```

How do I find the verices of each square in this grid and draw them?
Drawing the verices is not that important but would be nice to see them to get a better understanding for later.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to know the coordinates of the corner points (vertices)? - `column * WIDTH, row * HEIGHT`

Comment: Well since you have a grid, you can generate two for loops. One for the lines going over the rows (x-axis) and one for the columns (y-axis). Where the gap size are the `height` and `width` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The corner points (vertices) of the tile with the column index `column` and the row index `row` can be computed as follows:

```py
tl = column     * WIDTH, row     * HEIGHT
tr = (column+1) * WIDTH, row     * HEIGHT
bl = column     * WIDTH, (row+1) * HEIGHT
br = (column+1) * WIDTH, (row+1) * HEIGHT
```

However, this can be simplified by using a [pygame.Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

```py
tile_rect = pygame.Rect(column * WIDTH, row * HEIGHT, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

tl = tile_rect.topleft
tr = tile_rect.topright
bl = tile_rect.bottomleft
tt = tile_rect.bottomright
```

Comment: well yes, I need to know the vertices to later make a prims maze